# Write the statement using these predicates and any needed quantifiers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Are my answers correct?

> In the questions below suppose the variable x represents people,
>
> F(x): x is friendly
> T(x): x is tall
> A(x): x is angry.
>
> Write the statement using these predicates and any needed quantifiers.

i.  Some tall angry people are friendly.

```
Ǝ(x) [T(x) and A(x) => F(x)]
```

ii. If a person is friendly, then that person is not angry.

```
 f(x) => -A(x)
```

---

PS: In MathJax:

$\quad\exists x~[T(x)\land A(x)\to F(x)]$

$\quad f(x)\to \lnot A(x)$

Comment: Exists a tall and angry and friendly man. The second is correct

Comment: The second is incorrect.  It needs an universal quantifier.

Answer (score 2):

$i) \exists x(T(x) \land A(x) \land F(x))$

Some, ($\exists x$) tall  and angry and friendly people.

$i) F(x) \implies \lnot A(x)$, whichi is what you have is correct!

Comment: No the second refers to a free variable $x$, and thus says  "If a specific person is friendly...", rather than the required "if a(ny) person ..." .